# Monitoring and killing blocked threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat6

In a servlet-based app I'm currently writing we have separate thread classes for readers and writers. Data is transmitted from a writer to multiple readers by using `LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]>`, so a reader safely blocks if there is no new data to get from the writer. The problem is that if remote clients served by these reader threads terminate connection, Tomcat won't throw a broken pipe unless the writer sends in new data and attempts to transmit this new chunk to the remote clients. In other words, the following attack can be performed against our service:

1. Start a streaming write request and don't write any data to it at all.
2. Keep creating and dropping read connections. Since the writer doesn't produce any data, reading threads attached to it remain blocked and consume memory and other resources.
3. Observe the server run out of RAM quickly.

Should I create a single maintenance thread that would monitor sockets belonging to *blocked* reader threads and send `interrupt()` to those that appear to have lost connection to their respective clients? Are there any major flaws in the architecture described above? Thank you.

Comment: You could restrict the number of allowed incoming connections per ip-address.

Comment: Distributed attacks are nothing new, and this isn't likely to alleviate the problem much.

Comment: So what about keepalives and interrupt on communication exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me that the vulnerability lies in the fact that your readers wait forever, regardless of the state of the incoming connection (which, of course, you can't know about).

Thus a straightforward way to address this, if appropriate, would be to use the [poll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method on `BlockingQueue`, rather than [take](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29).Calling `poll` allows you to specify a timeout, after which the reader will return `null` if no data has been added to the queue.

In this way the readers won't stay blocked forever, and should relatively quickly fall back into the normal processing loop, allowing their resources to be freed as appropriate.

(This isn't a panacea of course; while the timeout is still running, the readers will consume resources.  But ultimately a server with finite resources will have some vulnerability to a DDOS attack - and this reduces its impact to a customisably small window, instead of leaving your server permanently crippled, at least.)

Comment: Andrzej, thanks, this looks very much like the solution I need. Should I also attempt to write e.g. an empty byte[] to the output stream when `poll()` returns `null` so that Tomcat has a chance to throw `IOException`?

Comment: It depends how you want to handle that error case (the timeout), which will depend on how your app works, what your infrastructure is like etc.  The main thing is that you get an opportunity to do this now rather than the reader blocking forever.

Comment: @David, Writing an empty byte[] is likely to do nothing. i.e. it won't detect a dropped connection. If you want to detect a dropped connection you need a timeout and/or a heartbeat.

Comment: @Peter, correct, writing an empty byte[] was a pretty stupid idea. Could you please clarify, timeout on what exactly to you suggest to track? I'm afraid pinging the client in a separate connection is  impossible, so we only can deduce its status from the a single servlet request/response object pair.

Comment: @David, I understand you are limited in the interaction you have with the client. However, there is a point at which you can expect to have received data from the client or you can timeout with the write fails.  If you have an open socket which nothing is sent for a while, you can close the connection and force the client to reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I taken in the past is to have blocking connections and only have reader threads.  When you want to write to multiple connections, you do that in the current thread.  If you are concerned about a write blocking for every, you can have a single monitoring thread which closes blocked connections.

You can still have resources tied up in unused sockets, but I would have another thread which finds unused sockets and closes them.

This leaves you will one thread per connection, plus a couple of monitoring threads.